# Kafka messages getting lost when consumer goes down

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream

Hello I am writing a kafka consumer-producer using spring cloud stream . Inside my consumer I save my data to a database , if the  database goes down I will exit the application manually .After restarting application if the database is still down as a result the application gets stopped again . Now if i restart the application for the third time the messages received in the middle interval(the two failures) are lost, kafka consumer takes the latest message , also it skips the message on which I exited the code.

Inbound and outbound channel binder interface

```
public interface EventChannel {

String inputEvent = "inputChannel";
String outputEvent = "outputChannel";

@Input(inputChannel)
SubscribableChannel consumeEvent();

@Output(outputEvent)
SubscribableChannel produceEvent();
}
```

Service Class  -

1) Producer Service

```
@Service
@EnableBinding(EventChannel.class)

public class EventProducerService{

private final EventChannel eventChannel;

@Autowired  
public EventConsumerService(EventChannel eventChannel){
this.eventChannel = eventChannel;
}

public void postEvent(EventDTO event) {
    MessageChannel messageChannel = eventChannel.produceEvent();
    messageChannel.send(MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(event)
            .setHeader(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .setHeader("partitionKey",event.getId().toString())
            .build());     
    }
}
```

2) Consumer Service

```
@Component
@EnableBinding(EventChannel.class)
public class EventConsumerService{ 

private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;
private final EventChannel eventChannel;

@Autowired  
public EventConsumerService(ApplicationContext applicationContext,EventChannel eventChannel){
this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
this.eventChannel = eventChannel;
}

@StreamListener(EventChannel.inputEvent)
public void saveUpdateCassandra(EventDTO event){
  Event newEvent = new Event(event);
  try{
     eventRepository.save(newEvent)
    } catch(Exceptione e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext,()-> 0); 
  }
}
```

Application properties file

```
#Spring Cloud Streams Configuration
##Broker
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=localhost:9092
##EventIngestion 
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.outputChannel.destination=Event
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.outputChannel.producer.partitionKeyExpression=headers.partitionKey
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputChannel.destination=Event
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.inputChannel.group=event-consumer-1
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.inputChannel.consumer.startOffset=earliest
```

Both application are running on independently So if my database goes down the consumer stops , on consecutive failures messages are getting lost

Answer (score 0):

First, I am not sure what are your expectation for `SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext,()-> 0);`, but you're essentially bringing down the entire application with everything hat may be running there.
Second, your message loss is due to the fact that Kafka binder has absolutely no knowledge that an exception had occurred and that it has to put message back on the topic. In fact from the binder's perspective and due to your code every message is always processed successfully. So. . .

Please remove `try/catch` from your StreamListener method and let exception propagate, thus letting binder know that there was an error.

Comment: Since the offset won't be committed until the listener exits normally, killing the JVM should cause redelivery  on restart. Unless enable.auto.commit is true, of course.

Comment: auto commit is on , even if i remove SpringApplication.exit messages are lost

Comment: @GaryRussell I understand offset is comitted as soon as the message is received but in my case mutiple message get lost

Comment: As I said, based on your code (what we can see from your post) messages are not lost, they are processed successfully - that is how framework sees it.

Comment: You are correct; I assumed `exit()` called `System.exit(n)`. It does not; so the listener exits normally and the record offset is committed.

Comment: @GaryRussell But only one message should get committed why mutiple messages are  getting committed

Comment: Most likely there are some default prefetch settings on Kafka side. The bottom line is from Kafka standpoint and from the standpoint of the framework there are no errors/exception. Based on your code your message handler and your application execute and exit successfully.  Further more the framework was never designed to be _exited_ in such way from message handler. That is a fundamental anti-pattern. Once again, let exception propagate (remove try/catch) and let the framework handle it.