# spring-boot 1.5.4 spring cloud stream manual offset commit behaviour if consumer (kube pod) restarts

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Hi we have been using old spring version and kafka 1.1 with following dependencies

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: -> 1.5.4.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config: -> 1.3.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka: -> 1.3.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka: -> 1.2.1.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.11.0.2 (*)
+--- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:0.11.0.2 (*)
```

I have following configuration in application.yaml file

```
spring:
  kafka:
    properties.security.protocol: SSL
    ssl:
      key-password: ${ABC_KEY_PASSWORD}
      keystore-location: file:${ABC_KEYSTORE}
      keystore-password: ${ABC_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD}
      truststore-location: file:${ABC_TRUSTSTORE}
      truststore-password: ${ABC_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD}
    consumer:
      enable-auto-commit: false
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        feed_fcpostprocessor_event:
          destination: app-fc-notification
          binder: abckafka
          group: app-fc-group
          consumer:
            partitioned: true
            concurrency: 2
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${ABC_BROKER_HOST:abc-kafka.aws.local:9092}
          autoCreateTopics: true
          autoAddPartitions: true
          replicationFactor: 3
          partitionCount: 2
        bindings:
          feed_fcpostprocessor_event:
            consumer:
              autoCommitOffset: false
      binders:
        abckafka:
          type: kafka
```

I found [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753093/kafka-messages-getting-lost-when-consumer-goes-down#) in stackoverflow. The answer has

> First, I am not sure what are your expectation for
>   SpringApplication.exit(applicationContext,()-> 0);, but you're
>   essentially bringing down the entire application with everything hat
>   may be running there. Second, your message loss is due to the fact
>   that Kafka binder has absolutely no knowledge that an exception had
>   occurred and that it has to put message back on the topic.

So does this mean Kafka does not know the consumer is down, in this case there is no communication from the consumer. I would have thought there will be rebalance happening and furthermore since the enable-auto-commit at kafka level and autoCommitOffset at bindings level is set to false. The offset will not commit and if the application starts again it will start from the last offset it missed or if rebalance happens then the other consumer will read from the offset where other consumer failed for the partition.

I believe my question is not duplicate and has to the point query.
If there is a question out there please point me to the answer.
Otherwise please clarify the behaviour.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, even though Boot 1.5 is no longer supported; you should be using spring-kafka 1.3.11 instead of 1.1; it has a much simpler threading model thanks to KIP-62. Before 1.3, things were very complicated to avoid rebalances.

But, even better, you should upgrade to supported versions of all projects, but at the very least, upgrade spring-kafka to 1.3.

Your expectation is correct; the records with the uncommitted offsets will be redelivered.